# Udacity Python Replace number in list

Tags: python

I'm not sure why my solution isn't working. I pass 'spy' through and then add one to the 3rd element of the list.

Thanks in advance!

```
# Define a procedure, replace_spy,
# that takes as its input a list of
# three numbers, and modifies the
# value of the third element in the
# input list to be one more than its
# previous value.

spy = [0,0,7]

def replace_spy(a):
    replace_spy[2] +1


# In the test below, the first line calls your 
# procedure which will change spy, and the 
# second checks you have changed it.
# Uncomment the top two lines below.

replace_spy(spy)
print spy
#>>> [0,0,8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function, you should perform on `a`.

```
def replace_spy(a):
    a[2] += 1
```

Comment: Dang...close. Thanks a bunch.